# How can I find an unknown word after a specific word?

Tags: python, string

I have this string "Hello, I bought apples, and sold bananas"
how can I get the value of the word after "bought" and the word after "sold" in python??

Comment: What do you mean by value?

Comment: Split() to a list. Get word after split.index(known_word)

Comment: @AnimeshMukherkjee I mean the word after a specific word.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
string = "Hello, I bought apples, and sold bananas"
string = string.replace(",","")
list_word = string.split(" ")
for i in range(len(list_word)):
    if list_word[i]=="bought" or list_word[i]=="sold":
        print(list_word[i+1])
```

output:

```
apples
bananas
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it. One way is to use regular expressions:

```
import re
s = "Hello, I bought apples, and sold bananas"
re.findall('\W(?:bought|sold)\W+(\w+)', s)
```